# Can Katalon Studio simulate different types of mobile devices while testing?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, automation, katalon-studio

I need to make sure that our software runs smoothly on every type of mobile android and ios device that are out there. Is Katalon studio capable of running tests on different types of devices without physically having those devices?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can run katalon in a different type of device or you can use **kobiton device** but it charges you money.